# Why is my image not showing in the modal?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, directory

Hello everyone I am trying to make a modal which shows an image when a button is clicked. But I ran into a problem and dont seem to understand why my image is not showing in my modal. I am using bootstrap 4.5.2 to make this modal.

When I use this url inside of the src: [//placehold.it/600x400](http://placehold.it/600x400). The image works fine but when I link the same image from my folder named resources the image does not load.

**Here is my code**

```
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                    Launch demo modal
                </button>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body" id="dynamic-content">
                                <img src="Resources/600x400.png" alt="officeMap" class="img-fluid">
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Here is my path**

[image: Here is my path]

Comment: Try `src="./Resources/600x400.png"`

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: Thanks for the console tip. The path should have been PlanPage/Resources/600x400.png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the file path to PlanPage/Resources/600x400.png solved the problem.